# three.js basic skeleton for animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

My goal is to have something like a 3 bones skeleton with only a sphere on each joint, for example, the arm with one sphere on the shoulder, one on the elbow and one on the wrist.

Everything I found uses some JSON loader which does everything about the building of the skeleton. Copying the doc of Three.js,  I made this code, which seems to display 3 sphere at the (0, 0, 0) point.

```
//all this lies in my init() function
var bones = [];
var shoulder = new THREE.Bone();
var elbow = new THREE.Bone();
var wrist = new THREE.Bone();

//link the bones
shoulder.add(elbow);
elbow.add(wrist);

//set the default position of the bones
shoulder.position.set(1, 1, 1);
elbow.position.set(1, 1, 2);
wrist.position.set(1, 1, 3);

//put all the bones in an array for the skeleton
bones.push(shoulder);
bones.push(elbow);
bones.push(wrist);

//this one is a global variable in my script
skel = new THREE.Skeleton(bones);

var m = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, emissive: 0x072534, shading: THREE.SmoothShading} );

//create the geometry for the spheres
var g1 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.2, 100, 100);
var g2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.2, 100, 100);
var g3 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.2, 100, 100);

for (var i = 0; i < g1.vertices.length; i++){
    // put the indices of the bones and the associated weights 
    //on each vertex of the geometry
    g1.skinIndices[i] = new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    g1.skinWeights[i] = new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0);
    g2.skinIndices[i] = new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0);
    g2.skinWeights[i] = new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0);
    g3.skinIndices[i] = new THREE.Vector4(2, 0, 0, 0);
    g3.skinWeights[i] = new THREE.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0);
}

//create the meshes
var s1 = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(g1, m);
var s2 = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(g2, m);
var s3 = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(g3, m);

//bind the meshes with the bones.
//I guesse this is the problematic part
s1.add(skel.bones[0]);
s1.bind(skel);
s2.add(skel.bones[1]);
s2.bind(skel);
s3.add(skel.bones[2]);
s3.bind(skel);

scene.add(s1);
scene.add(s2);
scene.add(s3);
```

I do have a `render()` and an `animate()` functions that are able to display some simple geometry. (I didn't put them here to avoid showing too much irrelevant code)

Actually, I have no idea what the `s1.add(skel.bones[0])` and the `s1.bind(skel)` really do: I saw this on an example and tried to copy what I saw, but it doesn't do what I want it to do. I just want to have each sphere at a different place, and to be able to use the skeleton for animation purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note, english is not my natural language!*

I agree, i can't find any really basic tutorial! Thats why i have experimented. The thing is a little difficult. There are some steps necessary, *"what the s1.add(skel.bones[0]) and the s1.bind(skel) really do"*  is only one of them.

First you have to create bones that depend on each other. Then you must calculate the dependence of the vertices on the bones, depending on specific geometry. Each vertex can depend up to four bones. In the example i calculated only two bones.

Now create a skeleton from the bones. The next step is the connection of bone, skeleton and mesh:
`skeleton = new THREE.Skeleton( bones );

mesh.add( bones[ 0 ] );   // add the first bone to the mesh

mesh.bind( skeleton );    // connect the skeleton`

To see the skeleton use: 
`skeletonHelper = new THREE.SkeletonHelper( mesh );`

The bones  in the example are created with the function `createBones(positionY, height, boneCount)`

Look for the different functions `skinIndexWeigtLatheBody()`and  `skinIndexWeightCylinder(geometry)`. Cylinder and lathe are easier to calculate than a sphere, because the vertices are more systematic and simply.

And finally animate with the bones. `mesh.skeleton.bones.rotation.x = ...`

The script:

```js
document.getElementById('move').checked = false;
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 20000 );
camera.position.set(-200,100,200);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setClearColor( 0xeeeeee, 1 ); 
container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);  
orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
orbit.enableZoom = true;
light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff,1,0); 
light1.position.set( -100, 300, 1000 );  
scene.add(light1);  
clock  = new THREE.Clock(true);
geometryNeck =  new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 6, 6);  
rSegmentCount = 8; // radial segments 
bodyHeight =   80; // body: LatheGeometry
boneBodyCount   =  3;  
boneBodySegCount  =  3;      
bodySegHeightCount =  boneBodySegCount * boneBodyCount; // segments total
boneBodyHeight  =  bodyHeight / boneBodyCount ; 
outlineBody = [   
 [0.01,-bodyHeight ],[20,-78],[35,-74],[42,-65],[45,-55],[44,-45],[30,-27],[10,0] //  from -bodyHeight to 0
]; 
pointsBody = [];   // Vector2 points  x,y
for ( var i = 0; i < outlineBody.length ; i++ ) {
   pointsBody.push(new THREE.Vector2(outlineBody[i][0], outlineBody[i][1]))
}
geometryBody = new THREE.LatheGeometry( pointsBody, rSegmentCount );  
skinIndexWeigtLatheBody();  // function
//---
limbRadius      =  4;
limbHeight      = 60;
boneLimbCount  =  3; 
boneLimbSegCount =  1;    
limbRadSegCount  =  6; // or 0.5*rSegmentCount;  
limbHeightSegCount =  boneLimbSegCount*boneLimbCount;
boneLimbHeight  = limbHeight/ boneLimbCount ; 
limbHalfHeight  = limbHeight * 0.5; 
openEnded     = false;    
geometryLimbs = [];
for (var i=0; i<2;i++){  // 2 limbs
  geometryLimbs[i] = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(limbRadius,limbRadius,limbHeight,limbRadSegCount,limbHeightSegCount,openEnded);
}
bonesBody = createBones( 0 , -boneBodyHeight, boneBodyCount); // function
bonesLimbs = [];
for (var i=0; i<2; i++){
              // function
 bonesLimbs[i] = createBones(-limbHalfHeight, boneLimbHeight, boneLimbCount); 
}
material  = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x896215, emissive: 0xa96415, wireframe: true, skinning: true}); 
meshNeck  = new THREE.Mesh(geometryNeck, material);
meshBody  = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometryBody, material );
meshBody.add( meshNeck ); 
geometrysLimbs = [];
meshesLimbs = [];
for (var i=0; i<2; i++){
 skinIndexWeightCylinder(geometryLimbs[i]);   // function
 meshesLimbs[i] =  new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometryLimbs[i], material);
}
meshesLimbs[0].rotation.z =  1.57;       // arm right 
meshesLimbs[0].position.x = -limbHalfHeight;
meshesLimbs[1].rotation.z =  -1.57;      // arm left 
meshesLimbs[1].position.x =  limbHalfHeight; 
skeletonBody = new THREE.Skeleton( bonesBody );  
meshBody.add( bonesBody[ 0 ] );      
meshBody.bind( skeletonBody );      
scene.add( meshBody );
skeletonHelperBody = new THREE.SkeletonHelper( meshBody );  
scene.add( skeletonHelperBody );
skeletonsLimbs = [];
skeletonHelperLimbs = [];
for (var i=0; i<2; i++){
 skeletonsLimbs[i] = new THREE.Skeleton( bonesLimbs[i] );             
 meshesLimbs[i].add( bonesLimbs[i][0] );        
 meshesLimbs[i].bind( skeletonsLimbs[i] );        
 meshBody.add( meshesLimbs[i] );
 skeletonHelperLimbs[i] = new THREE.SkeletonHelper( meshesLimbs[i] );  
 scene.add( skeletonHelperLimbs[i] );
}
//........................................................................
animate();
//........................................................................
function skinIndexWeigtLatheBody(){
 for ( var i =0; i<geometryBody.vertices.length; i++ ) {   
  vertexY =  geometryBody.vertices[ i ].y ;                    // only  y dependet
  skinIndex = boneBodyCount-1 - Math.floor((i % bodySegHeightCount)/ boneBodySegCount) ;  // skin-index,  bone 0 top     
  skinWeight = ( (bodyHeight - vertexY)  %  boneBodyHeight ) / boneBodyHeight ;         // weight
  geometryBody.skinIndices.push( new THREE.Vector4(    skinIndex, skinIndex+1, 0, 0 ) );  // allocation (2 from max. 4 bones)
  geometryBody.skinWeights.push( new THREE.Vector4( 1-skinWeight, skinWeight , 0, 0 ) ); 
 }
}
function skinIndexWeightCylinder(geometry){
 for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.vertices.length; i ++ ) {        
  vertexY =  geometry.vertices[ i ].y  +  limbHalfHeight;    // only  y dependet
  skinIndex = Math.floor( vertexY  / boneLimbHeight );             // bone 0: bottom  
  skinWeight = ( vertexY  % boneLimbHeight) /  boneLimbHeight;        // weight
  geometry.skinIndices.push( new THREE.Vector4(    skinIndex, skinIndex+1, 0, 0 ) );  // allocation (2 from max. 4 bones)
  geometry.skinWeights.push( new THREE.Vector4( 1-skinWeight, skinWeight , 0, 0 ) );
 }
}
function createBones(positionY, height, boneCount){
    bones = [];                   // base: bone 0
 basicBone = new THREE.Bone(); // base bone, length 0, not visible
 bones.push( basicBone );          
 basicBone.position.y = positionY; 
 prevBone = basicBone;         // previous bone for further
 for ( var i = 1; i < boneCount+1 ; i ++ ) {
  bone = prevBone.clone();              
  bone.position.y = height;  // at the right distance ...
  bones.push( bone );     //   lay down
  prevBone.add( bone );     //  ... each to the previous bone
  prevBone = bone;     // new previous bone       
 }
 return bones;
}
function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 var time =  clock.getElapsedTime();   
 if ( document.getElementById("move").checked) {  // HTML: <input type="checkbox" id="move"> move             
  for ( var i = 1; i < meshBody.skeleton.bones.length - 2; i ++ ) {  
   meshBody.skeleton.bones[ i ].rotation.z = 0.5*Math.sin( 1.8*time ) / meshBody.skeleton.bones.length;   
  }  
  for ( var i = 1; i < boneLimbCount+1; i++ ) {
   meshesLimbs[0].skeleton.bones[ i ].rotation.x = 0.6*Math.cos( 1.2*time ) / boneLimbCount; 
   meshesLimbs[0].skeleton.bones[ i ].rotation.z = 0.6*Math.sin( 1.2*time ) / boneLimbCount; 
   meshesLimbs[1].skeleton.bones[ i ].rotation.x = 0.6*Math.cos( 1.2*time ) / boneLimbCount; 
   meshesLimbs[1].skeleton.bones[ i ].rotation.z = 0.6*Math.sin( 3.14+1.2*time ) / boneLimbCount;
  }
  meshNeck.rotation.x = -0.20*(0.8+Math.sin( -1.57+1.2*time ));    
  meshNeck.rotation.y = -0.15*(0.6+Math.sin( -1.57+1.9*time ));
  meshBody.rotation.x = 0.2; 
  skeletonHelperBody.update();
  for ( var j = 0; j < 2; j++ ){ 
   skeletonHelperLimbs[j].update(); 
  } 
 } 
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="move">  move 

<script src="../js/three.min.84.js"></script>
<script src="../js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

The example is on http://threejs.hofk.de/ Skeleton Basic.

"Hummel Mara" (bumblebee Mara) shows there an extended example. A bumblebee with bones! It based on the skeleton examples before. The // comments are in german language, but the variables most named in english.

*Knochen - bone, Skelet - skeleton, Knoten - vertex , (- node ...), Ziffer - number, Tafel - table, bewegen - move ...   Take a translator german/english like dict.cc or google tanslater - so do i.*

---

By the way, don't use 100 sphere segments for the beginning.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for my super late answer ! This seems to work (and  I understand a bit better how the skeleton works). Even though I actually realized that using the basic hierarchy of three.js is enough for what I wanted to do.
Thank you !

Comment: Hi, I'm glad if you understand it better now. 
Maybe you can use moving or morphing meshes that are created differently. For this I have programmed a three.js addon. 
See renewed link http://threejs.hofk.de/ ( last example http://sandbox.threejs.hofk.de/ the // comments in english )